# Text and image are not aligned

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, html, css

I've got the following [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3uJKv/284/) which illustrates a problem I'm currently facing.  I have got an image tag, and want the text to be vertically aligned along the center of the image.  I have tried using `padding-bottom` but to no avail.

How can I achieve this? Essentially all I need is to move the text up.  I have also tried using a label and span, but the problem was there too.

Answer (score 0):

Add Extra css

```
.draggable img{
    float:left;
    margin-top:3px;
    padding-right:5px
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3uJKv/286/)

Answer (score 0):

is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/3uJKv/287/) whata re you to accomplish ?

i added this class :

```
.draggable img{
    float:left;
    padding-right:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You need to put "Text" in span tag suppose

```
<span class="user_text">Text Box</span>
```

And Css:

```
.user_text { 
  vertical-align:top;
}
```